# Definitive list of ABB colors

Tags: adjectives

I'm looking for a definitive list of ABB colors, like:

- `绿茵茵`
- `红彤彤`

I'm sure there's tons of these, green has, for instance, apart from the `绿茵茵` written above, `绿油油` as well as many others (I would assume).

The lists I've found online are usually pretty poor, i.e.:

> 绿油油、黄澄澄、白茫茫、紫盈盈、黑乎乎、红通通、亮晶晶

and that's about it...

- **Is there a definitive list of ABB colors?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a small research project, we can combine a few of those lists and then expand the result in collaboration. This then becomes the definitive list of ABB colors.

- 红扑扑, 红彤彤, 红通通, 红艳艳, 红通通, 红赤赤, 红光光, 红灿灿, 红殷殷
- 绿油油, 绿莹莹, 绿生生, 绿茸茸, 绿汪汪, 绿茵茵, 绿森森
- 白皑皑, 白花花, 白茫茫, 白蒙蒙, 白生生, 白嫩嫩
- 灰沉沉, 灰溜溜, 灰蒙蒙
- 黑沉沉, 黑洞洞, 黑糊糊, 黑茫茫, 黑蒙蒙, 黑黢黢, 黑黝黝, 黑压压, 黑漆漆, 黑生生
- 乌溜溜
- 青幽幽
- 碧澄澄
- 黄灿灿, 黄澄澄, 黄乎乎
- 金灿灿, 金煌煌, 金闪闪, 金亮亮, 金晃晃
- 蓝晶晶, 蓝盈盈, 蓝幽幽, 蓝湛湛, 蓝隐隐, 蓝莹莹, 蓝汪汪
- 紫乌乌, 紫莹莹, 紫茵茵, 紫盈盈, 紫通通, 紫微微, 紫灿灿, 紫葳葳
- 粉扑扑, 粉嘟嘟

My small contribution:

- 绿葱葱
- 红呼呼, 红润润
- 灰渌渌, 灰塌塌
- 碧油油
- 蓝瓦瓦